# Regex (PHP flavour) to match over multiplie lines OR not multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, multiline

I working on a Regex that'll match both the following pieces of syntax...

1.

```
aaa accounting system default  
 action-type start-stop  
 group tacacs+
```

2.

```
aaa accounting system default start-stop group tacacs+
```

The best I've got so far is...

`^aaa accounting system default (\n action-type |)start-stop(\n |) group tacacs\+`

The above Regex will match syntax number 2 but not 1? Pulling my hair out! (I know it's probably simple but I'm a Regex newbie) Any ideas?
There are spaces at the beginning of lines 2 & 3 in syntax piece number 1 but aren't being displayed to get a real look at how the syntax is presented take a look at the below Regex101 link. Thanks!

Here it is in Regex101...

https://regex101.com/r/lW8hT1/1

Comment: I edited the question so that the sample strings looked the same as at regex101.com. If the spaces can really be any, and there can be any amount of them, I would vote for my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the regular spaces in your pattern with `\s` that matches any whitespace:

```
'~^aaa\s+accounting\s+system\s+default(?:\s+action-type)?\s+start-stop\s+group\s+tacacs\+~m'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT2lL1/2)

Also, I made some other optimizations so that your two types of strings could be matched:

- `^` - matches start of a line (due to `/m`) modifier
- `aaa\s+accounting\s+system\s+default` - matches a sequence `aaa accounting system default` where `\s+` matches one or more whitespaces
- `(?:\s+action-type)?` - an optional  `action-type` (with one or more whitespace before `action-type`)
- `\s+start-stop\s+group\s+tacacs\+` - matches  `start-stop group tacacs+` that have 1 or more spaces in between the words.

Comment: Note that to match all Unicode whitespace, do not forget to add a `/u` modifier to the end of the regex: `'~^aaa\s+accounting\s+system\s+default(?:\s+action-type)?\s+start-stop\s+group\s+tacacs\+~mu'`

Comment: Great stuff and I learned something too! Thanks for your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. Note I also prefer [*non-capturing groups*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) with `?` quantifier applied to them (like `(?:...)?`) when I need to use an optional character sequence in my pattern (as Casimir notes in his answer).

Comment: Thanks again that non-capturing groups link helped me get a good handle on it

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you have redundant spaces in your optional groups:

```
^aaa accounting system default(\n action-type|) start-stop(\n|) group tacacs\+
```

You can write it in a better way using non-capturing groups `(?:...)` and the optional quantifier `?`:

```
^aaa accounting system default(?:\n action-type)? start-stop\n? group tacacs\+
```

*(in this way you avoid useless captures)*

Comment: Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

To match across multiple line you will need `DOTALL` flag:

```
/(?s)\baaa accounting system default.*?group tacacs\+/
```

Or else:

```
/\baaa accounting system default.*?group tacacs\+/s
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lW8hT1/2)